# Preserve notify icon autohide status when executable moves to another physical location

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, notifyicon

By default, Windows hides the notify icons in the taskbar, and user can see them by clicking on the arrow button. But user can drag those and drop them into the taskbar, so it'll be always visible. This preference will be saved for that executable.

However, my WPF app uses [Squirrel.Windows](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) for installation and update, and Squirrel.Windows creates a new executable (in a different path) for each update. So Windows will treat it as another executable, and that preference about notify icon is reset. (It hides again, even if user dragged it to taskbar in the previous version)

Is there any way I can preserve that preference of user across updates?

Maybe there's an identifier or something I can uniquely set? or any other ideas?

*I'm currently using `System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon` on my WPF app. But I'm open to using alternatives if an alternative can help solving this issue.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stop auto hiding tray notification icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148886/stop-auto-hiding-tray-notification-icon)

Comment: @dymanoid I don't think this question is a duplicate of that one. That question is talking about *overriding* the default system behavior, but this question is asking about preserving a kind of value in the system behavior. (I don't know, there might be a identifier that can be set, so Windows knows that this icon is the same as that icon from that executable?)